# jQuery Plugin DateTime Picker, How can I: Not need the validation check, when I don't pick any datetime, just leave the datetime picker box empty

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, datetimepicker, unobtrusive-validation

I used the method on https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker/ to create a datetime picker on my view page without any problems.

Code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" id="Date1" name="Date1" type="text"/>
    </div>
    <script>
        $("#Date1").datetimepicker();
    </script>
}
```

**This datetime picker filed “Date1” is not a required field**.
In data model:

```
[DisplayName("Date1")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime Date1 { get; set; }
```

After I submitted the form, I got the correct datetime value using code:

`DateTime theDate1 = Convert.ToDateTime(model.Date1)`

The problem is:

1. If I **remove *name="Date1"* from the INPUT text box**, I cannot get the correct datetime value, the value is always "01/01/0001".
2. If I **keep *name="Date1"* in the INPUT text box**, I can get the corrent datetime value. But, if I don't pick any datetime and just leave the atetime picker box empty, after submitting the form, I get a validation message: "The Date1 field is required."

How can I:

1. **Not need the validation check, even I don't pick any datetime, just leave the datetime picker box empty**.
2. Still get the correct datetime value if I picked a datetime.

Thanks,
Joseph

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: You need to make your property nullable - `public DateTime? Date1 { get; set; }` (and use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Date1, new { @class = "form-control" })` to generate the control. And you do not need `DateTime theDate1 = Convert.ToDateTime(model.Date1)` - its already `DateTime` - you do not need to convert it again. And you can remove `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` - that's only for `EditorFor()` and is used to add the `type="date"` attribute which you do not want